# CSS to style javascript dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, css

[image: Portal Image]

I'm needing to style a table that's dynamically created by javascript. I know how to style it if it were just a static HTML table but this is different and I'm not too familiar with javascript. Here is the javascript code:

```
[var aryPortalList = \[\];


function getPortalList() {
    var wP = window.location.protocol;
    var wH = window.location.host;
    var wPath = "ibi_apps/rs/ibfs/BIP/Portals?IBIRS_action=get";
    //http://webfocusclidev:8080/ibi_apps/rs/ibfs/BIP/Portals?IBIRS_action=get;
    var webfocusAPI = wP + "//" + wH + "/" + wPath;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: webfocusAPI,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('children').children().each(function() {
                var portal = {   Name: $(this).attr('bipName'),
                                 Link: "/ibi_apps/bip/portal" + $(this).attr('bipPath'),
                                 IconLink: "/ibi_apps/WFServlet.ibfs?IBFS1_action=RUNFEX&IBFS_path=" + $(this).attr('bipIconPath')
                              };  //var portal
                console.log("portal.name=" + portal.Name);
                if (portal.Name != "GlobalBI") aryPortalList.push(portal);
           }); //each
           console.log("Portals in List = " + aryPortalList.length);
        } //success function
    }); //ajax
}




function displayPortalList_Icon() {
    if (aryPortalList.length == 0) {
        var hTxt = "<p>You do not have access to any portals</p>";
        $("#portallist").append(hTxt);
    } else {
        var bRowAdded = false;
        var hTbl=$("<table id='tbl_portallist'></table>");
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('ingrPL_row');
        console.log("Portals in List = " + aryPortalList.length);
        for(var j=0; j < aryPortalList.length; j++) {
            var cell = $("<td align = 'center'></td>");


            var hTxt = $("<p>" + aryPortalList\[j\].Name + "</p>");
            var hLink = $("<a>").attr({"href": aryPortalList\[j\].Link,
                                   "target": "_blank"});
            var img = $("<img>").attr("src", aryPortalList\[j\].IconLink);
            img.width("100px");
            img.height("100px");
            console.log("hTxt=" + hTxt);
            hLink.append(img);
            cell.append(hTxt);
            cell.append(hLink);


            row.append(cell);
            bRowAdded = false;


            if ((j+1) % 4 == 0) {
                hTbl.append(row);
                bRowAdded = true;
                var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('ingrPL_row');
            }
        }
        if (!bRowAdded) {
            hTbl.append(row);
        }
        $("#portallist").html(hTbl);
    }
}


function displayPortalList_List() {
    if (aryPortalList.length == 0) {
        var hTxt = "<p>You do not have access to any portals</p>";
        $("#portallist").append(hTxt);
    } else {
        var bRowAdded = false;
        var hTbl=$("<table id='tbl_portallist'></table>");
        console.log("Portals in List = " + aryPortalList.length);
        for(var j=0; j < aryPortalList.length; j++) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('ingrPL_row');
            var cell = $("<td align = 'center'></td>");




            var hTxt = $("<p>" + aryPortalList\[j\].Name + "</p>");
            var hLink = $("<a>").attr({"href": aryPortalList\[j\].Link,
                                   "target": "_blank"});


            console.log("hTxt=" + hTxt);
            hLink.append(hTxt);
            cell.append(hLink);


            row.append(cell);
            hTbl.append(row);
        }


        $("#portallist").html(hTbl);
                console.log("portal.name=" + portal.Name);
    }
}][1]
```

And I've attached a photo of how the 'portal' looks.

What I need to do is space out the icons more and have the title's on the bottom of the icons, to look more like an 'iphone app'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about using css classes? You're doing it at this line: `var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('ingrPL_row');`

Comment: hmm.. what would I go about doing that? Sorry, fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can style it in the same way you style static elements
looking at your code I can see the table have an ID and the rows have classes

```
var hTbl=$("<table id='tbl_portallist'></table>");
var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('ingrPL_row');
```

so you can select those in your CSS file

## CSS

```
#tbl_portallist {
    /*table style here */
}
#tbl_portallist th {
    /*table head style here*/
}
#tbl_portallist tr {
    /*table row style here*/
}
#tbl_portallist td {
    /*table data (cell) style here*/
}
```

Comment: thank you kind sir. exactly what I needed to figure out! Cheers!

Comment: quick question now, how could I move the title of the portals below the pictures?

Comment: do you have a link to the page? if not. can you please share the html code for the finished table?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but try `cell.append(hLink);cell.append(hTxt);` instead of  `cell.append(hTxt);cell.append(hLink);` so we append the "hLink" element which contains the clickable image, then append the text below it. try it